# SwiftUI navigationTitle appear on a wired position and has a layout warning

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is a subView of my project
[image]
and it appears at a very low position
xcode also give me the layout warning

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailedView: View {
    var referFood:ReferFood
    @StateObject var recentFood=RecentSearched()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
                Form{
                    Section("名称")
                    {
                        Text("\(referFood.name)")
                    }
                    Section("保质期")
                    {
                        Text("\(referFood.qualityTime)")
                    }
                    Section("储藏方法")
                    {
                        Text("\(referFood.method)")
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("详细信息")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

It build successfully however when I drag the slider

Comment: Just remove `NavigationView` from `DetailedView`, it needs only one `NavigationView` - in root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationView` should be in `RootView` only.
Example in documentation

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

is shown below:

Destination View:

```
struct ColorDetail: View {
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        color.navigationTitle(color.description)
    }
}
```

RootView:

```
NavigationStack {
    List {
        NavigationLink("Mint") { ColorDetail(color: .mint) }
        NavigationLink("Pink") { ColorDetail(color: .pink) }
        NavigationLink("Teal") { ColorDetail(color: .teal) }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Colors")
}
```

ps:
`NavigationStack` is the new version of `NavigationView` which is now deprecated in `iOS 16`.